# Передача массива в Highcharts

Tags: php, yii2, highcharts

Передаю данные массива, но к каждому значению добавляются кавычки, в связи с чем график не отписывается. Если передаю просто переменную, тоже самое

```
echo Highcharts::widget([
                'options' => [
                    'title' => ['text' => 'Заказы по месецам'],
                    'xAxis' => [
                        'categories' => ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Мар','Апр', 'Май', 'Июн','Июл', 'Авг', 'Сен','Окт', 'Нояб', 'Дек']
                    ],
                    'yAxis' => [
                        'title' => ['text' => 'Заказы']
                    ],
                    'series' => [
                       ['name' => date('Y'), 'data' => array_values($arr_orders)],
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

В JS выводит

```
   jQuery(function ($) {
Highcharts.setOptions([]); new Highcharts.Chart({"chart":{"renderTo":"w0"},"title":{"text":"Заказы по месецам"},"xAxis":{"categories":["Янв","Фев","Мар","Апр","Май","Июн","Июл","Авг","Сен","Окт","Нояб","Дек"]},"yAxis":{"title":{"text":"Заказы"}},"series":[{"name":"2018","data":["0","0","1"]}]});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo Highcharts::widget([
                'options' => [
                    'title' => ['text' => 'Заказы по месецам'],
                    'xAxis' => [
                        'categories' => ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Мар','Апр', 'Май', 'Июн','Июл', 'Авг', 'Сен','Окт', 'Нояб', 'Дек']
                    ],
                    'yAxis' => [
                        'title' => ['text' => 'Заказы']
                    ],
                    'series' => [
                       ['name' => date('Y'), 'data' => array_map(function($val){ return (int) $val },array_values($arr_orders))],
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

Или на этапе формирования массива $arr_orders переводите значения в Integer

Comment: Спасибо большое